# Algebra 1 help needed

Tags: algebra-precalculus

One-third of the people from country A claim that they are from country B, and the rest
admit they are from country A. One-fourth of the people from country B claim that they
are from country A, and the rest admit they are from country B. In a combined census of
the two countries, one-half of the total population claimed to be from country A. What
is the ratio of the population of country A to that of country B? I got the answer: 3/2 but I just want to confirm.

Comment: I agree with that result.  Note:  the way you describe the problem, using words like "claim" and "admit", there's a suggestion that people might lie about their national origin, for whatever reason.  However, since we aren't told anything about the way people might be expected to lie, I just ignored all that and took the numbers at face value.

Comment: Thank you for your comment.

Answer (score 0):

Let

A=no. of people from country A

B=no. of people from country B

From the given data we can construct the following simultaneous equations

$\frac{2}{3}A+\frac{1}{4}B=\frac{1}{2}$

$\frac{1}{3}A+\frac{3}{4}B=\frac{1}{2}$

By solving them we get,

$A=\frac{3}{5},B=\frac{2}{5}$

So,

$\frac{A}{B}=\frac{3}{2}$